# C++ Truncating an iostream Class

Tags: c++, file, iostream, truncate, stringstream

For a project I'm working on for loading/storing data in files, I made the decision to implement the iostream library, because of some of the features it holds over other file io libraries. One such feature, is the ability to use either the deriving fstream or stringstream classes to allow the loading of data from a file, or an already existent place in memory. Although, so far, there is one major fallback, and I've been having trouble getting information about it for a while.

Similar to the functions available in the POSIX library, I was looking for some implementation of the truncate or ftruncate functions. For stringstream, this would be as easy as passing the associated string back to the stream after reconstructing it with a different size. For fstream, I've yet to find any way of doing this, actually, because I can't even find a way to pull the handle to the file out of this class. While giving me a solution to the fstream problem would be great, an even better solution to this problem would have to be iostream friendly. Because every usage of either stream class goes through an iostream in my program, it would just be easier to truncate them through the base class, than to have to figure out which class is controlling the stream every time I want to change the overall size.

Alternatively, if someone could point me to a library that implements all of these features I'm looking for, and is mildly easy to replace iostream with, that would be a great solution as well.

Edit: For clarification, the iostream classes I'm using are more likely to just be using only the stringstream and fstream classes. Realistically, only the file itself needs to be truncated to a certain point, I was just looking for a simpler way to handle this, that doesn't require me knowing which type of streambuf the stream was attached to. As the answer suggested, I'll look into a way of using ftruncate alongside an fstream, and just handle the two specific cases, as the end user of my program shouldn't see the stream classes anyways.

Comment: What exactly is your objective? Do you want to limit the amount which can be written to a stream? This would be easily done with a filtering `std::streambuf`. Truncating after the fact depends on where the data was written to and, obviously, can be done for all streams. For example, if you have written characters to the console or to a socket there is no way of getting them back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't truncate an `iostream` in place. You have to copy the first N bytes from the existing stream to a new one. This can be done with the `sgetn()` and `sputn()` methods of the underlying `streambuf` object, which you can obtain by `iostream::rdbuf()`.

However, that process may be I/O intensive. It may be better to use special cases to manipulate the `std::string` or call `ftruncate` as you mentioned.

If you want to be *really* aggressive, you can create a custom `std::streambuf` derivative class which keeps a pointer to the preexisting `rdbuf` object in a stream, and only reads up to a certain point before generating an artifiicial end-of-file. This will look to the user like a shorter I/O sequence, but will not actually free memory or filesystem space. (It's not clear if that is important to you.)

Comment: note that you should **not** `delete` the result you get back from `rdbuf()`: the stream buffer is supposed to be owned either by the derived stream class (e.g. `std::fstream` typically embeds the `std::filebuf` into the object) or by an external entity which installed a stream buffer using `rdbuf()`. In either case, calling `rdbuf()` doesn't transfer ownership to you!

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Right, sorry, fixed. That solution is even more hackish than I realized… iostreams is a mess.